# Pattern matching vs. condition in a function

Tags: functions, pattern-matching, conditional, upvalues

I'm trying to learn stuff from pattern matching but I found sometimes pattern matching does not work as I expected. Could anyone explain why the below outputs are not same? Thank you.

And could anyone also explain why the upvalue setting of b and c cannot use as pattern matching as in my last three codes?

[image: My output on two examples]

```
Clear[a, b, c, g4, g5]
g4[x_^y_, z_] := u[x, y, v[z]] /; {IntegerQ[y], IntegerQ[z]};
g5[x_^y_Integer, z_Integer] := u[x, y, v[z]];
g4[a^3, 2]
g5[a^3, 2]
g4[a^3, c]
g5[a^3, c]
IntegerQ[b] ^= True; IntegerQ[c] ^= True;
g4[a^b, c]
g5[a^b, c]
```

Answer (score 4):

For `g4`, your condition doesn't evaluate to `True` or `False`. Specifically, `{IntegerQ[y], IntegerQ[z]}` will always evaluate to a pair of booleans, which won't ever actually be equal to `True` and so that "condition" won't ever be satisfied. You could do something like this instead:

```
g4[x_^y_, z_] := u[x, y, v[z]] /; And[IntegerQ[y], IntegerQ[z]]
```

As for the `UpSet` question, once you fix the condition on `g4` and evaluate the `UpSet` definitions of `IntegerQ` for `b` and `c`, then `g4[a^b, c]` will evaluate as you expect (`u[a, b, v[c]]`). However `g5[a^b, c]` will remain unevaluated, because pattern matching and conditions are different mechanisms that aren't logically interchangeable. But if you had a `g6` defined like this:

```
g6[x_^y_?IntegerQ, z_?IntegerQ] := u[x, y, v[z]]
```

then `g6[a^b, c]` would evaluate to `u[a, b, v[c]]` (again assuming the `UpSet`s for `IntegerQ`).

A bit more explanation. A pattern like `y_Integer` matches when the `Head` of whatever is bound to `y` is `Integer`. So, for example,

```
g5[foo^Integer[bar], Integer[blah]]
```

will evaluate to

```
u[foo, Integer[bar], v[Integer[blah]]]
```

However, even with the corrected condition,

```
g4[foo^Integer[bar], Integer[blah]]
```

will evaluate to

```
g4[foo^Integer[bar], Integer[blah]]
```

because `IntegerQ[Integer[bar]]` is `False`.

Comment: Hi lericr, I really appreciate your explanation which makes a lot of sense to me. I also tried to define something like g4[x_^y_, z_] := u[x, y, v[z]] /; IntegerQ[y] /; IntegerQ[z]; This one gives same result as your g4 using And function. Are they same thing by any chance? :)

Comment: They aren't the same structurally. Your version is a nested `Condition`, and mine is a single `Condition`. But logically they would be equivalent.

Comment: Okay glad to learn all this! The signs in MMA can sometimes be confusing but it is really a good start for me. I'm grateful for your time and help lericr!